# non-compatible actual argument in feature call in collection make_from_separate

Tags: generics, generic-list, eiffel, eiffel-scoop

Don't understand where I'm wrong here...

```
class
    LINKED_LIST_SEP[G]

inherit
    LINKED_LIST [G]

create
    make,
    make_from_iterable,
    make_from_separate

feature {NONE} -- Initialization

    make_from_separate (other: separate like Current)
        do
            default_create
            across
                other is l_item
            loop
                check
                    attached {G} {SCOOP_UTIL}.any_from_separate (l_item) as l_v
                then
                    extend (l_v)
                end
            end
        end

end -- class
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unconstrained formal generic parameter, the implicit constraint is `detachable separate ANY`. But feature `any_from_separate` expects `separate ANY`.

The following solutions are possible:

1. Add a test that `l_item` is not void before calling `any_from_separate`.
2. Change signature of `any_from_separate` to accept detachable types. In this case, however, its result would also become detachable.
3. Add a constraint `separate ANY` to the formal generic parameter of class `LINKED_LIST_SEP`.

Comment: Nice, I was missing the detachable, I remembered the separate part. The most extendible I see is testing for attached before adding it. Thx. Could be nice to add that as a hint on compilation with type of Generic #1 it will be more explicit for those who don't learned well their theory ;)